# Variables in sending email using smtplib

Tags: python, html, email

For a project I want my program to send emails to my own account. I am currently using the smptlib to do so. The emails that I am sending are written in HTML. The problem is that I do not know how to include variables inside this email because they alter. Can someone help me?

I have already tried to add different syntaxes like

```
y = 20
x = ('percentage: %i', 20)
x = f'percentage: {y}'
```

but they do not seem to work in the triple quote manner with the msg.add_alternative function

Here is some of my code:

```
import smtplib

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'test'
msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = 'niek9999@gmail.com'

msg.set_content('Hello')
percentage = 32 

msg.add_alternative(("""
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" 
...
<li style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 19.6px;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22.4px;">percentage: <PERCENTAGE HERE> %</span></li>
..."""
subtype= 'html')


with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

I want to reach the goal of having a this percentage inside the email that is going to be send.

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give your actual and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `f"""{percent}"""` is certainly working on Python 3.7.0. I just tried it out. Please post to code you run and the error you experiencing.

```
(base) C:\Users\andrás>python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> percent=20
>>> s=f"""percent is: "{percent}\""""
>>> s
'percent is: "20"'
>>>
```

Comment: This does work in my python too but when I put it like this:

msg.add_alternative((f"""
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" 
...
<li style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 19.6px;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22.4px;">percentage: {percentage} %</span></li>
..."""
subtype= 'html')

it says invalid syntax even with extra ()s

Comment: Doesn't the missing comma before the `subtype` is giving the error?

Comment: And the code contains 2 `(` but only 1 `)`. This is another syntax error

Comment: I have it litteraly like this

msg.add_alternative((f"""html stuff percentage: {percentage}"""), subtype= 'html')

But it still gives me a syntax error